# Android: Replacing images in GridView array after OnItemClick

Tags: android, arrays, gridview, onclick

I have a grid view that looks roughly like this (each image will be a different in the end):

[image]

When the user clicks any image in the array, I want that image to change to this:

[image]

If they click again it changes to this:

[image]

And then clicking again reverts back to:

[image]

Here's my code so far, just creating a GridView with Imageadapter:

```
public class GridScroll extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // CHANGE IMAGE HERE
            Toast.makeText(GridScroll.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
}
```

}

And:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.lifestyle_5,R.drawable.lifestyle_6,
        R.drawable.lifestyle_7,R.drawable.lifestyle_8,
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.lifestyle_1,R.drawable.lifestyle_2,
        R.drawable.lifestyle_3,R.drawable.lifestyle_4,
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4,
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.lifestyle_1,R.drawable.lifestyle_2,
        R.drawable.lifestyle_3,R.drawable.lifestyle_4,
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.lifestyle_1,R.drawable.lifestyle_2,
        R.drawable.lifestyle_3,R.drawable.lifestyle_4,
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4,
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 
        R.drawable.icon_4, R.drawable.icon_4, 

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, we need to do two things:

**1. Change the drawable of the item when it is clicked.**
In `onItemClick(...)`, change the drawable for the View that is passed to you. This View will be the same one that you created in `getView(...)` of your adapter.

**2. Make sure that the item is shown with the correct drawable the next time it comes on screen.**
To do this, keep track of the state of each item. Every time you make a view for the item in `getView(...)`, assign it the correct drawable for its state.

---

Here is an example. I am assuming ImageAdapter is a subclass of ArrayAdapter. If not, then you will need to modify this code to work with what you are doing.

*Put these somewhere:*

```
private static final int WHITE = 0;
private static final int TEAL = 1;
private static final int MAROON = 2;
private List<Integer> mStates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

*This goes in your ImageAdapter:*

```
// Map each state to its graphics.
private Map<Integer, Integer> mStateResources = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
mStateResources.put(WHITE, R.drawable.white);

public void add(...) {
    super.add(...);

    // The new item will start as white.
    mStates.add(WHITE);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //ImageView image = ...

    // Set the correct image for the state of this item.
    int state = mStates.get(position);
    int resId = mStateResources.get(state);
    image.setImageResource(resId);
}
```

*In your OnItemClickListener:*

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Change the image and state for this item.
    int nextState;
    switch(mStates.get(position)) {
    case WHITE:
        nextState = TEAL;
        break;
    case TEAL:
        nextState = MAROON;
        break;
    case MAROON:
        nextState = WHITE;
        break;
    }

    // Set the new state and image for this item.
    mStates.put(position, nextState);
    int resId = mStateResources.get(nextState);
    image.setImageResource(resId);
}
```