# How to change image in GridView when clicked

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

i need some help for my project.
i have an ImageView inside GridView. i have trouble to change the image when the image is clicked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455681/android-replacing-images-in-gridview-array-after-onitemclick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look over this

[Android: Replacing images in GridView array after OnItemClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455681/android-replacing-images-in-gridview-array-after-onitemclick)

or

```
   gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View imgView, int position, long id) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imgView;
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.newImage);
        }
    });
```