# Android Grid View cell background changes

Tags: android, gridview, textview, getview

I having a problem getting GridView to keep it's data consistent while scrolling. Basically, I am working on a simple bingo app and I want to be able to scroll around the screen so that the user can see a full 5x5 grid. I have been using this question to try to figure out what is going on([Android: Replacing images in GridView array after OnItemClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455681/android-replacing-images-in-gridview-array-after-onitemclick)) If I understand this correctly, I need to modify getView() to not use a recycled view for each cell. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    final Bingo bingo = new Bingo();
    final String[] stuff = new String[25];
    for (int i=0;i<25;i++){
        stuff[i]=bingo.getValue(i);
    }
    stuff[12]="Free Space";

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stuff);


    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

           bingo.open(position);
           if (bingo.isOpen(position))
           v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(12, 15, 204));
           else
           v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(128, 128, 128));


            if (bingo.bingo()==true){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        //((TextView) v).getText(),
                        "BINGO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This code sort of works. The backgrounds change and it interfaces fine with my bingo class, but when scrolling, random cells change color and sometimes cell values just disappear leaving blank spaces. I tried the following code after the adapter declaration, but it crashes as soon as it loads up on the device.

```
   {
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup                                    parent){
            Context mContext = null;
            TextView textView= new TextView(mContext);
            if (convertView == null) {  


           textView.setText(stuff[12]);
            } else {
                textView = (TextView) convertView;
            }

            if (bingo.isOpen(position))
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(12, 15, 204));
            else
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(128, 128, 128));

            return textView;
        }
    };
```

I am just having a problem making sense of how to make this work for text view. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You use a null context to create a textview so error occurs

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){ 
        // here you declare the context is null
        // Context mContext = null;         
        TextView textView;
        if (convertView == null) {  
            // error occurs because the context is null
            // TextView textView= new TextView(mContext); 
            // so try to use
            textView = new TextView(parent.getContext()); 
            textView.setText(stuff[12]);
        } else {
            textView = (TextView) convertView;
        }

        if (bingo.isOpen(position))
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(12, 15, 204));
        else
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(128, 128, 128));

        return textView;
}
```